# How did Hermione get galleons?

Tags: harry-potter

It is implied in HP books that Hermione Granger is reasonably affluent, compared to eg. Ron Weasley.

At the start of Prisoner of Azkhaban, she had 10 galleons left to spend after purchasing what was needed for school.

Is it indicated anywhere in books, how she got any wizarding money at all, her parents being muggles? Were they made aware of money needs by the school  and were given enough information to arrange exchange with Gringot's?

Comment: Her parents know enough about the wizarding world to visit Gringotts and exchange money; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15518/what-do-the-gringotts-goblins-do-with-muggle-money. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @Valorum Essentially yes, that was what I was looking for. Didn't remember that part of the book. I still wonder if there JKR has explained it in some more detail in some interview or elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Hermione's parents know to exchange Muggle money for Galleons at Gringotts.

> [...] [Mr. Weasley] was distracted almost at once by the sight of Hermione’s parents, who were standing nervously at the counter that ran all along the great marble hall, waiting for Hermione to introduce them.
>
> “But you’re Muggles!” said Mr. Weasley delightedly. “We must have a drink! What’s that you’ve got there? Oh, you’re changing Muggle money. Molly, look!” He pointed excitedly at the ten pound notes in Mr. Granger’s hand.
>
> <sub>— *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, chapter 4 "At Flourish and Blotts", by J.K. Rowling</sub>

Comment: Yes, thank you I missed that. Would be nice, if there was some more detail somewhere else, but this is at least in the book.

Comment: My hat's off to Rowling for her ability to make a what would otherwise be a normal situation seem weird from another point of view.  She always seems to have a knack for making such things funny.