# Why Don't the Weasleys Use Transfiguration to Improve Their House?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, spells

I am probably missing something obvious, but why wouldn't the Weasleys use transfiguration spells to improve their shabby house (or get someone to do this for them)?

Comment: Probably the same reason my lawn needs mowing. Because they can't be bothered.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/107129/976

Comment: Perhaps they aren't structural engineers, and if they tried to transfigure their house in any significant way they'd risk collapsing it. Perhaps the house matches their aesthetic and they like it the way it is. Maybe Arthur spends all of his time tinkering with muggle artefacts instead of working on home improvement projects and Molly is busy with children.

Comment: Maybe they did - could be there's just limits on what can be easily done, or how frequently, or when multiple properties (appearance vs stability vs security vs ability to support other magic) have to be juggled at once.