# How long did Barty Crouch Jr intend to stay at Hogwarts after Voldemort's return?

Tags: harry-potter

Was he intending to stay on as a spy after the return of Voldemort, or planning to flee? 
If the latter was true, why didn't he do so after he felt the Dark Mark burn?

Comment: His job was to get Harry to the cup, and hence to the graveyard. After that, I don't think anything is said. I don't believe he would have thought he could remain undetected after that.

Comment: Just a guess, but I think Voldemort would have wanted him to stay. He believed his existing spy at Hogwarts (Snape) had turned sides, so a new spy was in order: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/58863/3567

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, because of the curse on the Defense Against the Dark Arts teachers, he likely wouldn't have stayed beyond the end of the school year. However, like you acknowledge, he could have stayed longer.

Voldemort himself notes that he didn't respond to the Dark Mark summoning:

> “And here we have **six missing Death Eaters**… three dead in my service.
>   One, too cowardly to return… he will pay. One, who I believe has left
>   me forever… he will be killed, of course… and **one, who remains my most
>   faithful servant, and who has already reentered my service**."

Because of his deep involvement in the plan, I suspect he didn't need to turn up to the graveyard. The graveyard scene, with the Death Eaters summoned, was about saying "I'm here, I'm back, bow to me once more". Voldemort takes the opportunity to reprimand those who had turned from him in the years since his disappearance. Barty Crouch Jr had already done his bit.

So, I think him not responding to the summons was intentional, and the plan was for him to keep up his disguise as long as possible. Remember, Harry was supposed to die in the graveyard, and it would have been disguised as your standard Triwizard Tournament death - so providing it all went to plan, Fake Moody could have stayed at Hogwarts, at least for a little bit longer, gaining what knowledge he could. He could also have taken this opportunity, and his trusted status, to quietly silence any suspicions about untoward goings-on in the maze. He would eventually have rejoined his master, once Hogwarts held nothing for him, or once Voldemort's return was known.

Had Voldemort's night gone to plan, he wouldn't have *needed* to leave Hogwarts immediately, and it makes sense for him to stick around and see what he can. As we see, it also works out well (at least for a bit) that he stays at Hogwarts, since it offers a backup when Voldemort's plan fails - he tries to kill Harry again (though doesn't succeed thanks to Dumbledore and McGonagall).

Comment: All good points—except it would be rather hard to simply chalk up Harry’s death as a standard Triwizard death. He would almost certainly have been killed by Voldemort himself with _Avada Kedavra_, which would be instantly detectable. _Prior Incantato_ would show that none of the other contestants was the killer… and they’d kind of be back to square one.

Comment: That's true. However, I wonder if, had the plan in the graveyard succeeded, and Harry had indeed been killed by Avada Kedavra, what would they have done with his body? It seems kind of unlikely that they'd send it back to the maze. He may have just been reported missing in action, until Voldemort chose to reveal otherwise (proof of Potter's death) later in the year, when stealth was no longer important.

Comment: That could be. A Triwizard disappearance would probably be easier to explain (though I doubt it would fool Dumbledore, at least).

Answer (score 2):

Crouch stated in chapter 14 that he intended to stay in Hogwarts for only one year.

> "But you're behind - very behind - on dealing with curses," said
>   Moody. "So I'm here to bring you up to scratch on what wizards can do
>   to each other. **I've got one year to teach you how to deal with Dark -**"
>
> "What, aren't you staying?" Ron blurted out.
>
> Moody's magical eye spun around to stare at Ron;
>   Ron looked extremely apprehensive, but after a
>   moment Moody smiled - the first time Harry had seen him do so. The
>   effect was to make his heavily scarred face look more twisted and
>   contorted than ever, but it was nevertheless good to know that he ever
>   did anything as friendly as smile. Ron looked deeply relieved.
>
> "You'll be Arthur Weasley's son, eh?" Moody said. "Your father got me out of
>   a very tight corner a few days ago... **Yeah, I'm staying just the one**
>   **year**. Special favor to Dumbledore... **One year, and then back to my**
>   **quiet retirement."**

Answer (score 0):

It was the end of the school year, so he couldn't have stayed. And considering Voldemort's DADA curse, he wouldn't be able to return next year, Mad-Eye disguise or not (though admittedly he probably wouldn't know this, unless told directly by Voldemort).

Comment: There was enough of the school year left for him to find out what Dumbledores plans were concerning Voldermorts return. We know that Snape would have alerted him instantly. I don't believe that Dumbledore knew that Mad eye was responsible until he removed Harry from his sight. Also I don't think the dark lord or Barty would ever have expected Harry to escape the graveyard. This means that the Barty not joining the dark lord the instance the mark burned meant he was likely planning on staying at least till the end of the school year?

Comment: Most likely - I guess alexwlchan'c comment applies most here. Though since it's not addressed in canon all of this is speculation (besides the fact that he couldn't return next year)

Answer (score 0):

Fake Moody told his students he was only staying for a year; however, maybe he was betting on Dumbledore saying, "Oh, Moody, we're all in horrible danger, stick around for a while."

Answer (score -1):

I have a theory. I think that he was going to stay forever. I believe that Voldemort intended to kill Harry, then use his hair for a polyjuice potion, then use the portkey to go back, pretending to be Harry so that he could kill Dumbledore, then Barty crouch Jr. would stay as DADA teacher, or something. Now, to back this theory: the only portkey in any of the books that was two-way (it would not only take you to where it was going, but also take you back to where it left from) was the Triwizard cup, meaning that Voldemort most likely had some plan to go back to Hogwarts. Also, Voldemort risked letting Harry have his wand, and duel him after 15 years of being "less than the meanest ghost", which must be a disadvantage on his part. I believe that this is because he needed to be the true owner of Harry's wand so that it would work for him when he went to Hogwarts, completing his disguise. Now, you are most likely going "but why not just kill Harry?" and I say that it's for two possible reasons:

1. Voldemort never really understood wands. He may have heard about how if you beat someone in battle, there wand will belong to you, but not understood that you just have to win, not kill, or that you just have to overpower them, whether its in battle or not.
2. He wanted to prove that harry winning was a fluke (most likely of the two), and thought he could kill two birds with one stone.