# Did Snape know what was going to happen in Goblet of Fire?

Tags: harry-potter

We all know Snape

> is / was a follower of the Dark Lord.

Did Snape know what was coming for Harry in *The Goblet of Fire*?

Answer (score 12):

**No.**

At his rebirthing ceremony, Voldemort believes that Snape has [“left him forever”](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/58889/3567). He’s only “redeemed” (in Voldemort’s eyes) after Harry has returned to Hogwarts. It’s unlikely that Snape is getting regular updates on Voldemort’s plans if he’s believed to be a traitor.

Remember that Voldemort wasn’t sure which of his Death Eaters were still loyal to him, so he kept an exceptionally tight circle. Only Crouch Jr and Wormtail knew about the plan; everybody else was in the dark. That includes Snape.

Of course, they all knew that *something* was happening – the Dark Mark was evidence of that – but the details were unknown.

Answer (score 5):

No. Snape had a fairly good idea that something was happening due to the resurgence of the dark mark. He may also have been told about Harry's dreams by Dumbledore however I doubt it. That said knowing that the Dark Lord was attempting to come back in general is different than knowing the exact plans.

The only people that were aware of the details was Riddle, Pettigrew and Crouch Jr. All the other death eaters including Snape were uninformed prior to the graveyard.

Comment: And Nagini. Don't forget Nagini. And, come to think of it, Winky may have known at least part of the plan, too, though she would of course be unable to reveal it.

Answer (score 4):

Snape knew Voldemort was getting stronger and he realized when Voldemort returned.

> “There,” said Snape harshly. “There. The Dark Mark. It is not as clear as it was an hour or so ago, when it burned black, but you can still see it. Every Death Eater had the sign burned into him by the Dark Lord. It was a means of distinguishing one another, and his means of summoning us to him. When he touched the Mark of any Death Eater, we were to Disapparate, and Apparate, instantly, at his side. This Mark has been growing clearer all year. Karkaroff s too. Why do you think Karkaroff fled tonight? We both felt the Mark burn. We both knew he had returned. Karkaroff fears the Dark Lord’s vengeance. He betrayed too many of his fellow Death Eaters to be sure of a welcome back into the fold.”
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 36, The Parting of the Ways</sup></sub>

Snape did not know that Voldemort and Barty Crouch Jr. had planned to use Harry to help Voldemort return because the plan was known only to Voldemort, Barty Crouch Jr., Peter Pettigrew and Barty Crouch Sr.

> “Yes. After a while he began to fight the Imperius Curse just as I had done. There were periods when he knew what was happening. My master decided it was no longer safe for my father to leave the house. He forced him to send letters to the Ministry instead. He made him write and say he was ill. But Wormtail neglected his duty. He was not watchful enough. My father escaped. My master guessed that he was heading for Hogwarts. My father was going to tell Dumbledore everything, to confess. He was going to admit that he had smuggled me from Azkaban.
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 35, Veritaserum</sup></sub>

The rebirthing ceremony was well planned and it was triggered at the last possible moment.

> There was complete silence now, except for Winky’s continued sobs. Then Dumbledore said, “And tonight...”
>
> “I offered to carry the Triwizard Cup into the maze before dinner,” whispered Barty Crouch.
>
> “Turned it into a Portkey. My master’s plan worked. He is returned to power and I will be honored by him beyond the dreams of wizards.”
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 35, Veritaserum</sup></sub>

We can give Snape a clean chit on this one.