# How many wands were chosen for Pottermore?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore, pottermore

If we believe this the answer to this question [How many possible types of wands can Ollivander make?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24347/how-many-possible-types-of-wands-can-ollivander-make); there are 19,152 different wand combinations.

Pottermore has brought back Sorting (House and Wands). The wand that chose me could be considered one of the more rare types...

I was just wondering on how rare that might actually be as I doubt the site was programmed with all various combinations. While it would be easy and necessary to have all 3 wand cores; would having *all* of the remaining variables be necessary?

**Is it known how many wands are able to choose their wizard on Pottermore?**

Comment: They just combine each of the aspects and leave you to find out what yours means - so why couldn't they have all 20000 possibilities? There are definitely only a very few images but they're not as relevant.

Comment: @ThruGog I was thinking based on the number questions/answers asked  on the quiz to determine the outcome be the limit.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UAZ59lsiqap1pQAAjr1ncy589LLHtHfoxyfFCrYqPGY

Comment: Does not add to my answer in any meaningful way, but [according to Pottermore's CEO, there are "10,000 or so" possible computations.](https://youtu.be/0mHdHmQRUP8?t=1296)

Comment: @ibid Canon confirmation is always a good thing!

Comment: [Rowling says 30,000](http://www.snitchseeker.com/harry-potter-news/jk-rowling-full-harry-potter-reading-club-webchat-discussion-transcript-now-available-91349/): *I think there are 30,000 and something wand combinations you can get, so you get a really personalized wand.*

Comment: And I just found out that the new Pottermore has less possible results. See edit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### 15,834 Possible outcomes from taking the quiz

Luckily for you, someone (by the name of Kira Starthestral) already reversed engineered the wand quiz, and compiled the results into [a nice spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UAZ59lsiqap1pQAAjr1ncy589LLHtHfoxyfFCrYqPGY). (Note that you have to look through ALL the tabs, which contain complete information. The first is only a selection of some wand surveys.) Pretty much this entire answer is either copied directly from that spreadsheet or was made based on its data. (You can also [use my pdf](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BzktoPZRvTdaUDZsT3lSa3RIVWM) if you find that easier.)

It is possible that the actual quiz was modified for the new Pottermore, (just like the Sorting Quiz was). However, seeing as the questions have not changed, this is probably unlikely.

It is even more likely that I messed up on my math somewhere.

- 38 woods
- 21 lengths
- 14 flexibilities
- 6 colors
- 3 cores
- 3 shapes

Which would give a total of 603288 theoretical combinations. (The other answer arrived at 19152 by miscounting the number of flexibilities and by ignoring shape and color.)

We can lower that upper bound even further by looking at the answer choices:

1. Height - (3 choices)
2. Eye color - (9 choices)
3. Birthday date - (2 choices)
4. Trait most proud of - (7 choices)
5. Path - (3 choices)
6. Fear - (5 choices)
7. Artefact - (7 choices)

Putting the bound down at 39690, Showing that some combinations are impossible to get.

However, this is also not good, because some wands have multiple possible ways to reach.

Going back to our list of results,

> **The length** is determined by the artefact you choose from the trunk and your height.
> **The core** is determined by your greatest fear and the artefact you choose from the trunk.
> **The flexibility** is determined by the trait you're most proud of and the date of your birthday.
> **The wood** is determined by your eye colour, the trait you're most proud of and the path you choose.
> The wood determines the wand's **colour**.
> **The shape** of the wands is determined by the flexibility.

Length has a unique output for each of it's 21 inputs.
Flexibilty/shape has a unique output for each of its 14 inputs.

Core and wood are more tricky as they overlap with other questions (making not all results possible) and have less outputs then inputs (making numeorus duplicates.)

I calculated cores and wood as having 13/5 and 145/7 possible results per wand respectfully. (No idea what the proper terminology for this is.)

Thus, **there are a total of 15,834** (21*14*13/5*145/7) possible wand results to get from the quiz.

More numbers:
39690 possible answer combinations
603288 possible theoretical possible wands (including shape & color)
33516 possible theoretical possible wands (not including shape & color)
15834 possible different quiz results
17682 wands within the bounds of results but impossible to arrive at based on the current structure of the quiz.

Basically, if you are trying to get a specific characters wand, you probably won't be able to. You could get Harry's or Ron's, but others can be impossible by either requiring results outside the bounds of the quiz (e.g. mahogany), having wands impossible to reach, or having wands that are impossible to reach while maintaining the other info that we know of the characters (e.g. eyecolor).

**Note:** Due to (what is probably) a bug in the new Pottermore, there are currently only thirteen possible flexibilities, resulting in just **14,703** possible results.

**Note 2:** Due to (what is probably) *another* bug in the Wizarding World / HP Fan Club site, there are currently only twelve possible flexibilities, resulting in just **13,572** possible results.

Comment: How did they change the Sorting quiz out of interest? I haven't re-Sorted

Comment: @ThruGog - It's on my list of things to self-answer. Basically, (not counting the artwork), they added a question, changed the question order, & removed hatstalls. We don't have enough data to determine past that.

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister - Result is mainly determined by which 7(now 8) of the 28 (now 29) questions are shown. Delete your account (much easier on the new Pottermore), rejoin, and repeat. After 10 times, take the house that you're getting most often.

Comment: AWESOME ANSWER!! Just one question where/how does the shape/color come into play?

Comment: @Skooba - In the image of the wand that gets shown. http://i.imgur.com/0GzLBMS.png

Comment: @ibid Oh, I see. Wow, the sorting was way more complex than I thought!

Comment: [33,000 confirmed by press release](https://web.archive.org/web/20150202124747/http://press.pottermore.com/j-k-rowling-announces-pottermore/)

Comment: @ThruGog - A bit late, but I've covered it [in this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/158262/55866).

Comment: @ibid - Good job! Well remembered ;-)

Comment: So my daughter's result was a 9 3/4", pine wood, dragon heart string.
It's not on your spreadsheet, must be pretty obscure.

Comment: @Nic - *Note that you have to look through ALL the tabs, which contain complete information. The first is only a selection of some wand surveys.*

Comment: If not all possibilities are "Possible", then it may be that not all wood & flexibility combinations are compatible, as an in-universe explanation.

Comment: @Turbo - When I say not possible, I mean that when they ported over the quiz they overwrote those flexibilities with duplicates of similar flexibilities. [Here's a chart.](https://i.imgur.com/hkHZ6Lt.png)

Comment: Given "a few" more years, we might end up with *1* possible result.