# What's the world magic demographics?

Tags: harry-potter

What's the known figures for the world population of magical humans? Further details, where available, is appreciated - population levels across geographical regions etc.

Comment: Also, there is the question [Is there an estimate of how many wizards work for the Ministry of Magic?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7446/is-there-an-estimate-of-how-many-people-work-for-ministry-of-magic/8002#8002) for further information on wizarding demographics. :)

Answer (score 2):

**We don't know.**

There are apparently sufficient wizards to merit [eleven wizarding schools](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Wizarding_school) around the world (typically one or two per continent). Assuming student numbers at those schools are much the same as a Hogwarts ([600 students](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59171/why-is-the-intake-of-students-for-hogwarts-so-small-compared-to-the-number-of-wi) in total, with approx 40 new students each year) and with wizards living an average of around 100 years, that gives a total worldwide magical population of around half a million wizards and witches.

That being said, JKR's maths is appalling and it's not entirely clear that she gave any serious thought to worldbuilding so these numbers (riddled as they are with my assumptions) may prove to be **dramatically wrong.**

Comment: I think it's okay to take the numbers JKR has given us, and to use them to *estimate* population and demographic numbers (Note: For the sake of full disclosure, I answered the second question I offered up.).

Comment: @Slytherincess - The problem is that her number make almost no sense. Also there's a fair amount of what can only be described as "*cultural blindness*", regarding the whole of Africa as a single country with a single wizarding academy, for example.

Comment: Oh, I agree with you. I guess my point is those are the only numbers we have for British wizards. If she gave us more numbers for different countries, maybe (maybe?) we could get some logical numbers. :)