# Can the Elder Wand betray its owner?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore, deathly-hallows

I have a vague recollection that the Elder Wand is quite happy to betray its owner for a more powerful wizard.

The best I could find was a quote from [screenrant](https://screenrant.com/harry-potter-wandlore-elder-wood-trivia/):

> Because this wand thinks so highly of itself, it is incredibly finicky with its ownership. This wand will only choose a witch or wizard who shows great talent and power when it comes to using magic. And if that witch or wizard does not meet the strength standards the wand has over them, then this wand will betray its owner and seek new ownership.

Is that supported in the books?

Comment: https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/965566203694649344

Comment: Depends, most likely every owner who loses it will probably feel _betrayed_.

Comment: Also, how do you know you are _meant_ to be its owner? Voldemort was pretty sure it betrayed him, but it belonged to Harry.

Comment: [This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/51970/21267) will also help shed light on the behaviour of the Elder Wand.

Comment: If the Elder Wand can,  then it would certainly betray Harry in the last battle, but it didn't.  Voldemort is obviously a "wizard who shows great talent and power", while the Elder Wand hold its loyalty to me.

Comment: @Harry But Voldemort doesn't have the *Power of Love* (Cue 80s power ballard).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much everything we know about the Elder Wand is summed up [here](https://www.wizardingworld.com/features/everything-we-know-about-the-elder-wand). That said, the answer is:

**Presumably no.**

There's nothing in the current canon suggesting that the Elder Wand can choose to betray its current owner or to change allegiances on its own volition and without a "reason" to do so.
While his allegiance is highly volatile and changes easily, as far as we know it still needs a trigger to switch loyalties, that is, being stolen, forcefully taken, lost in a duel, etc.

But keep in mind that the Elder Wand doesn't keep old loyalties. Most wands remember its original owner and keep a certain degree of loyalty towards him/her, but the Elder Wands is *presumably* the only wand that doesn't care about old owners.

Maybe with the upcoming movies of Magic Beasts and Where to Find Them, we'll know more about the Elder Wand, since we'll surely bear witness to the duel between Grindelwald and Dumbledore, where Grindelwald lost the Elder Wand.

Answer (score -2):

Well, technically, yes. The Elder Wand will always faithfully serve its real master, but if its creator demands anything, it will comply, even betraying its master. If you didn't get it, I am talking about Death.

Also, if the Elder Wand sees anyone with a higher power level or talen, it will strain towards the person, and try to influence both the individuals to fight, so that the stronger person wins it over.

Comment: That's presuming [Death is _real_](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/54713/21267).

Comment: It seems you blend the *legend about* the elder wand and basically *the one ring* here. Do you have anything to substantiate these points?