# Do Squibs have to be pure-blood?

Tags: harry-potter, muggles

If a Muggle was born of a wizard/witch and a Muggle, is that person a Squib, or is that reserved to people born from pure-blood families?

(Related: [Is a Squib a Muggle?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14526/is-a-squib-a-muggle))

Comment: Also related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9254/is-it-genetically-possible-for-a-squib-to-produce-magical-offspring

Comment: Reopening because this asks what types of families can produce Squibs, which isn’t covered in if Squibs are basically Muggles.

Answer (score 5):

## Squibs aren’t only pure-blood - they can have a Muggle parent.

If a wizard and Muggle have a nonmagical child, it’s a Squib. In the Pottermore writing on Dolores Umbridge, it’s mentioned that her parents (a wizard father and Muggle mother) have two children together - Dolores, a witch, and her brother, who was a Squib.

> Dolores Jane Umbridge was the eldest child and only daughter of Orford Umbridge, a wizard, and Ellen Cracknell, a Muggle, who also had a Squib son. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Dolores Umbridge (Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/dolores-umbridge))*</sup></sub>

This shows that Squibs can be born to a wizard/Muggle couple - in that case the nonmagical child would still be considered a Squib, not a Muggle, despite having one Muggle parent. It also shows by extension that Squibs don’t have to be pure-blood, as any child with a Muggle parent isn’t.

Answer (score 2):

No I don't think so. Kendra Dumbledore was definitely a Muggle-born witch:

> 'Dumbledore's mother was a terrifying woman, simply terrifying. Muggle-born, though I heard she pretended otherwise -'
>
> 'She never pretended anything of the sort! Kendra was a fine woman,' whispered Doge miserably, but Auntie Muriel ignored him.

And yet nobody has any problem speculating that Arianna was a Squib:

> '- proud and very domineering, the sort of witch who would have been mortified to produce a Squib -'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - p.129 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 8, *The Wedding*

Comment: What does Kendra being muggle-born have to do with Ariana?

Comment: @Alex ? Muriel thought Ariana was a Squib? And her mother was Muggle born so she's not Pure blood she's half blood

Comment: But the question wasn't about (all) half-bloods; it was specifically about people with a muggle parent.

Comment: @Alex The question body also says "or is that reserved to people born from pure-blood families?" and the titular question is "Do Squibs have to be pure-blood?" I'm assuming 2+ years ago I didn't take "If a Muggle was born of a wizard/witch and a Muggle" to be deliberately and carefully restricting the type of non-pure-blooded person the question was about, I probably understood it as a simple attempt to quickly restate the titular question so as to provide an actual question body. I think this info remains interesting and relevant, but Bella's answer is really good, if not book canon

Comment: In any case, since in the Harry Potter universe, people only distinguish pure blood, half blood and Muggle-born, if a Squib can be one type of half blood, surely it can be another type of half blood

Comment: But there is a reasonable difference between a half-blood that has two magical parents and a half-blood that has a muggle parent. The former is expected to be magical; hence, if not magical he/she is an anomaly and called a squib. If one parent is a muggle, though, maybe the kid is just a muggle like the parent.

Comment: @Alex Perhaps to us, but nowhere in Harry Potter canon are there subdivisions of half-blood. To the people who care about such things in universe, a half-blood has a Muggle ancestor in their reasonably traceable family tree. And the people who don't care about such things don't care about such things. If Ariana can be called a Squib then any half blood can

Comment: Nobody has PROVED that Ariana is a squib.

Comment: @SiriusBlack ? I don't think it's very likely Ariana was a Squib, I said "And yet nobody has any problem speculating that Arianna was a Squib:" My reasoning was, if Squibs had to be Pure-Blood then people would of course realise that Arianna couldn't have been a Squib, but everyone thought that it was quite possible for her to be a Squib even though she was not Pure-Blood. Therefore it seems that the general understanding in the Harry Potter universe is that it's quite possible for half-bloods to be Squibs, therefore they don't have to be Pure Blood...

Comment: I mean it's possible that the general understanding, or Auntie Muriel's understanding, was false, but you're not gonna get perfect, mathematical truth in answering a question like this, you can only make reasonable deductions. It's also possible that nobody put 2 and 2 together, especially if they were actively looking for conspiracy theories, but really these two facts are so close together in Muriel's line of reasoning I don't think one can just say Muriel overlooked the fact that only Pure-Bloods can be Squibs when she suggested Arianna was one. I think Squibs don't have to be pure-blood

Answer (score -2):

A *Muggle* wouldn't be born of a wizard/witch and Muggle, instead a ***Squib*** would be born. That's because since the child contains traits of a Muggle and a magical person, he/she wouldn't be purely non-magical, and he/she would have some magical characteristics inherited from the magical parent. Hence the child would become a ***Half-Blood Squib***...

Comment: Do you have any references to back this up?