# What's the mechanism by which magic is hereditary?

Tags: harry-potter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do Muggle-borns end up with magical ability?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3345/how-do-muggle-borns-end-up-with-magical-ability)

Was it ever clarified how magic is passed on hereditarially so that both children of two wizards or half bloods can both be fully magical?

Comment: I agree @GabeWillard - it's a dup!!!  What now, how to close it?

Comment: For a non-canon, but rather enjoyable analysis, try the Fanfic -- Harry Potter and the Methods of Rationality; that's a significant plot point in a few chapters.

Comment: @zipquincy I believe you can delete it by clicking the delete button under the question, since it has no answers. Alternately, wait a bit, and it'll have the 5 needed VTC's.